# How to print values of tuples using my own Tuple Class in C++

Tags: c++, class, tuples

Hi everyone I am new to programming and especially OOP. I am given this *.h file, which contains a Tuple class

```
/*  * Tuple.h  * 
 *  
 *             */ 
#ifndef TUPLE_H_ 
#define TUPLE_H_ 
#include <string> 
class Tuple 
{ 
 public: 
 Tuple ( );
 Tuple (int n, std::string s);
 virtual ~Tuple ( );
 bool setTup (int n, std::string s);
  std::string getTup(int n);
 private:
 int n;
 std::string s;
};
#endif /* TUPLE_H_ */
```

I am asked to:

- create two objects called Tup1 and Tup2
- the private variables n and s should only bet set if n>0 and s!=" ",
  otherwise they are set to n = 0 and s= " "
- Tup1 should use default constructor
- Tup2 should use the explicit constructor with the arguments
  (2,"second")
- Tup1 should then be intialized using the setTup method with the
  arguments (1,"first")
- Finally I should print the content of Tup1 and Tup2 by using the
  getTup method and the tuples should only be printed if the function argument n in getTup is equal to the obj variable n.

I assume I should make the control that the private variables are only set in the setTup method (like this) or is this wrong?..when I compile it seems to be doing the right thing:

```
bool Tuple::setTup(int n, std::string s)
{

    if (n > 0 && s != " ") {
        this->n = n;
        this->s = s;
        return true;
    }

    else {
        this -> n = 0;
        this -> s = " ";
    
    }

    return false;
}
```

I make sure that

1. Tup1 should use default constructor
2. Tup2 should use the explicit constructor with the arguments (2,"second")
3. Tup1 should then be intialized using the setTup method with the
   arguments (1,"first")

In the main.cpp like this:

```
int main()
{
    Tuple Tup2(2, "Second"); //Tup2 using explicit constructor with given arguments
    Tuple Tup1; // Tup1 using default constructor
    Tup1.setTup(1,"First "); //using setTup to set Tup1 with given arguments
```

However I am completley lost on how to print the values of the Tuples using the getTup method

The method takes an int argument n, but what should it return so that I can print the values of Tup1 and Tup2?

and how am i supposed to make sure that values of Tup1 and Tup2 are only printed if  the method argument n in getTup isequal to the object-variable n? ..I assume what is being asked  is to check that getTup(n) of Tup1(n,"s") the two n's should be equal...but I still have not idea how to do this

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Tup1 should use default constructor"_ and later you write _"Tup1 should then be **intialized** using the setTup method"_.  How? `Tup1` was already initialized. `setTup` may assign new values to `Tup1`'s member variables, but you can't initialize more than once.

Comment: You say nothing about the implementation of the constructors. Can you show it, or is your problem already in that implementation?

Comment: Are you sure that the instructions say `" "` (a space character), and not `""` (the empty string)?

Comment: Hint: printing "nothing" (i.e. the empty string) looks exactly the same as not printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The signature in the header file already tells you what the function returns:

```
std::string getTup(int n);
^^return value
            ^^function name
                   ^^parameter type
                        ^^parameter name
```

For the other part:

You already know how to use `if`. And you know how to access the objects private members.

So your code should look like this:

```
std::string getTup(int n){
  // check if parameter n matches private member n
    // if yes (true), then return the private member s;
    // if not, return an empty string, so nothing gets printed.
}
```

Comment: Hi infinitezero thanks very much! - one question: you comment to applying the getTup method:  ' // check if parameter n matches private member n' - should the if statement look like this -> if this->n == n  ??

Comment: @karlkarlsen Yes, of course you need parentheses: `if( this->n == n ){ ... }`. One further remark: if you choose a different name, that doesn't clash with the parameter name, you don't need to write `this->` in most of the cases

Comment: @karlkarlsen if you found this answer helpful, you can give it an upvote. And don't be afraid to ask more question on stackoverflow! Happy programming!